# Grep Command execution within a loop gives error

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to create a small program to count the no of lines in a set of log files based some user supplied time frame.I am currently in the last step and due to some reason when i execute the program it fails with the below error 
    **grep: |: No such file or directory
    grep: wc: No such file or directory**

The execution happens at line 6 in the code below. Line 7 shows a sample command that i am trying to execute. If I comment line 6 and uncomment line 7, it executes. I might be missing something simple. Appreciate your help. The values on those variables are given below

fileName="' summary_* | wc -l"
command="grep '"
comm=ived>20161215110

```
1 for (( z=0; z<($interval/10); z++ ))
2 do
3       comm=$tempCommand$count
4       let "count = $count + 1"                                
5       #echo "$command$comm$fileName"
6       totalCount=`$command$comm$fileName`
7       #totalCount=`grep 'ived>20161215110' summary_* | wc -l`
8       echo $totalCount
9 done
```

Comment: `grep ... | wc -l` might be simplified to just `grep -c ...`

Comment: For starters, why `grep | wc -l` when you could `grep -c`?  Also, I would throw in some debug output that shows the contents of `$command`, `$comm`, and `$filename`.

Comment: There are a set of files on which i am applying this grep. I just need the final total count

Comment: I have updated the variables in the question

Answer (score 1):

The shell recognizes the `|` metacharacter at the very beginning of parsing. When expanding a variable value, it's already too late, so `|` behaves as a literal vertical bar, i.e. as if you ran

```
grep 'ived>20161215110' summary_* \| wc -l
```

You can use a function instead of a variable.

Comment: So essentially what change do you want me to make in the script to get it work?

Comment: @Shawn: I can't run your script, you haven't shown enough code. See [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).